# Expansion Panel Icon Transitions (Mat. UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/yp9lmvwo1x In this sandbox you can see the icon is an arrow and the rotation transition is perfectly fine. I'm using a `+ x` for the icon, however, and I need a 45 degree rotation. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try it where? That will not override the default MUI animation.

Comment: Ngl not a very helpful answer/comment. I'm coming here because I was unable to find a way to do this in docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [ExpansionPanelSummary source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ExpansionPanelSummary/ExpansionPanelSummary.js#L66) you can find the syntax for the default styles controlling this:

```
      '&$expanded': {
        transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg)',
      },
```

You can get a 45 degree rotation by using the following:

```
  expandIcon: {
    "&$expanded": {
      transform: "translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)"
    }
  },
  expanded: {}
```

then in the JSX:

```
<ExpansionPanelSummary
          classes={{
            expandIcon: classes.expandIcon,
            expanded: classes.expanded
          }}
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        >
```

[image: Edit expandIcon rotation]

Comment: How to do this now?